# Interesting jQuery Animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have been playing around with jQuery for a bit now, and am really curious how far someone would be able to take this.

Has anyone seen (or written) some jQuery code that did some memorable animation?  Something that stood out.  I am quite interested in seeing some ideas.

Please post your experiences.  Thanks.

Comment: I guess it should be community wiki question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... here's more good stuff:

http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/09/making-a-3d-engine-in-jquery/

Answer (score 5):

[how about this one: http://www.willjessup.com/sandbox/jquery/solar_system/rotator.html](http://www.willjessup.com/sandbox/jquery/solar_system/rotator.html)

Answer (score 4):

Something that I didn't create, but [this](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/) is something I fell in love with.
It's a simple use of jQuery and it can be edited to do great things.
The simple modal page slide, is just awesome to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

I really like [this use of the Google Maps API with an overlay and animation](http://blog.codebrain.co.uk/post/2009/08/10/Google-Maps-UK-Postcode-Selector-with-jQuery.aspx). Click on the map to scroll to the postcode of the county, which will briefly flash.